# Ideal configuration setting for max.tasks for Kafka Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to run a HDFS Source Connector and a FileStream Source Connector. I was wondering how it would work if we set `tasks.max` > 1. Isn't it the connector's job to make sure that the parallelism is handled correctly?

For example, would it not be a problem for FileStream Source Connector if there are more than 1 tasks accessing the file? How will the connector know which line is being read by which task and how to make sure that there is no clash among tasks?

OR

Is it that the setting should be `tasks.max=1` for such connectors where such a problem can occur?

Comment: FileStream Source is not intended to be seriously used, only as an example implementation.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answers that are below and on any post, please remember to mark them as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such problem, since according the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html#connect-managing-config-connectors):

> `tasks.max` - The **maximum** number of tasks that should be created for this connector. The connector may create *fewer* tasks if it cannot achieve this level of parallelism.

For example, for `File Stream Source Connector` `max.tasks` is simple [ignored](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/ee352be9c88663b95b1096b7a294e61857857380/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceConnector.java#L76-L87), while for `JDBC Source Connector` the real number of tasks is defined as [minimum](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/f0e379f14c35dcc316898c166c63e26ce4df71eb/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/JdbcSourceConnector.java#L152) of `tasks.max` and tables count.

Comment: Thank you!
But, the way I see it, Kafka Connector by default does not know how to handle the file. We need to implement that logic in the `poll()` method. right?

Let us say I set `tasks.max` to 3. We need to handle which of the three tasks handles which line of the file. That is the reason the `tasks.max` is ignored.

Comment: Yes, real tasks count depends on specific data source and logic of polling